# Display parent term based on child term in views

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have a vocabulary with the following structure:

```
Vocabulary
Parent term 1
    Child term 1.1
        Child term 1.1.1
    Child term 1.2
        Child term 1.2.1
Parent term 2
    Child term 2.1
        Child term 2.1.1
    Child term 2.2
        Child term 2.2.1
```

Based on the above structure of taxonomy terms, I have a view of all the terms of last level like,

```
Child term 1.1.1
Child term 1.2.1
Child term 2.1.1
Child term 2.2.1
```

Now, i want to create the view, which list me 2nd level of taxonomy term by passing term id of the 3rd level.

> Example:- If i pass term id of Child term 2.2.1 in contextual filter, i should see the Child term 2.1 as a result of view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **Taxonomy term: Parent term** in RELATIONSHIPS of the view.

[image]

Then in the field section select the **Relationship**

[image]

That's it. Whatever term you enter in the contextual filter it fetches the parent term of it.

Here is entire exported view (example).

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'tag_relation';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$view->human_name = 'Tag relation';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Tag relation';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Relationship: Taxonomy term: Parent term */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['parent']['id'] = 'parent';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['parent']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_hierarchy';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['parent']['field'] = 'parent';
/* Field: Taxonomy term: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['relationship'] = 'parent';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['link_to_taxonomy'] = TRUE;
/* Contextual filter: Taxonomy term: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['name']['default_action'] = 'empty';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['name']['default_argument_type'] = 'fixed';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['name']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['name']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['name']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['name']['limit'] = '0';
/* Filter criterion: Taxonomy vocabulary: Machine name */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['id'] = 'machine_name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_vocabulary';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['field'] = 'machine_name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['value'] = array(
  'tags' => 'tags',
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'tag-relation';
```